# Смена кодировки MySQL с latin1 на UTF-8

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, charset

Развернут apache и MySQL на Ubuntu 14.04LTS.

**Вывод** `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE'character%'`

Variable_name - Value

character_set_client - utf8

character_set_connection - utf8

character_set_database - utf8

character_set_filesystem - binary

character_set_results - utf8

character_set_server - utf8

character_set_system - utf8

character_sets_dir - /usr/share/mysql/charsets/

**Вывод** `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'collation%';`

Variable_name - Value

collation_connection - utf8_general_ci

collation_database - utf8_general_ci

collation_server - utf8_general_ci

**php подключение к базе и вывод кодировки:**

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
require_once ('../config.php');
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli(DB_URL, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
printf("Изначальная кодировка: %s\n", $conn->character_set_name());
mysqli_query($conn, "SET NAMES 'UTF-8'");
printf("А теперь: %s\n", $conn->character_set_name());
$conn->set_charset("utf8");
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

**Вывод браузера**

Изначальная кодировка: latin1 А теперь: latin1

Думаю, это главная причина проблемы, связанной с незаписывающимися кириллическими данными в БД из формы. Числа пишутся, кириллица - нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Привет! Ты сначала выводишь на экран кодировку, а потом ее задаешь, поменяй эти 2 строчки местами, чтобы выглядело так:

```
$conn->set_charset("utf8");    
printf("А теперь: %s\n", $conn->character_set_name());
```